# Why this branch instruction of ARM doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arm

Now I am writing a library to mock the trivial function for C/C++. It is used like this: `MOCK(mocked, substitute)`
If you call the mocked function, the substitute function will be called instead.

I modify the attribute of code page and inject the jump code into the function to implement it. I have implemented it for `x86 CPU` and I want to port it to `ARM CPU`. But I have a problem when I inject binary code.

For example, the address of substitute function is `0x91f1`, and the address of function to mock is `0x91d1`. So I want to inject the ARM branch code into `0x91d1` to jump to the substitute function.

According to the document online, the relative address is

```
(0x91f1 - (0x91d1 + 8)) / 4 = 6
```

so the binary instruction is:

```
0xea000006
```

Because my arm emulator(I use Android arm v7 emulator) is little endian, so the binary code to inject is:

```
0x060000ea
```

But when I executed the mocked function after injecting branch code, segment fault occurred. I don't know why the branch instruction is wrong. I have not learned ARM architecture so I don't know whether the branch instruction of ARM has some limits.

Comment: you sure it wasnt the injection that caused the fault?  what operating system are you running on and how did you insure you had data access to .text?

Comment: The bytes to insert are `0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0xea`, but if you insert it as an integer, then you should keep the `0xea000006` as the endianness will be applied on that as appropriate. Presumably your emulator has some debugging feature, use it.

Comment: Make sure the code is not in Thumb. Most ARM platforms these days default to Thumb.

Comment: Aren't there alignment requirements for the ARM? Word boundary for functions perhaps? 0x91f1 just looks suspicious.

Comment: Which ARM architecture?

Comment: @user1666959: Right. Word alignment for ARM code, and halfword alignment for Thumb code. When doing a `BX` from ARM code to Thumb code you'd set the lsb of the target address, but the actual address you're jumping to still has to be aligned.

Comment: What @Jester said. Are you writing the new instruction as a single word with `STR`? If so you don't need to worry about flipping the bytes. There's no need to write it as individual bytes with `STRB`, since unlike x86, ARM instructions are always 32 bits and word-aligned.

Comment: As several people have pointed out, you're placing an ARM 32-bit opcode into what appears to be a thumb code segment. Try using opcode `0xe00e` (`0x0e` `0xe0` in little-endian bytes). That's a thumb unconditional branch `0x20` bytes from the current instruction address.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses you are branching to is odd numbered, meaning they are in Thumb mode.

There is an obvious problem with your approach.

If target is in Thumb mode, you either need to be in Thumb mode at the point you are branching from or you need to use a `bx` (Branch and Exchange) instruction.

Your functions are in Thumb mode (+1 at the target) but you are using ARM mode branch coding (B A1 coding?), so obviously either you are not in Thumb mode or you are using ARM mode instruction in Thumb mode.

Comment: This answer looks right except for the last sentence. While the `B` branch assembler mnemonic uses an absolute address in the assembly source, the instruction op code contains a 26-bit `PC` relative offset (24 bits specified in the opcode with two implicit least significant zero bits).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! TIL something.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM family allows loading of registers with values.  One of those registers is the PC (Program Counter).

Some alternatives:

1. You could use a function to load the PC register with the
   destination address (absolute).
2. Add the PC register with an offset.
3. Use a multiply-and-add instruction with the PC register.
4. Push the destination register onto the stack and pop into PC
   register.

These choices plus modifying the destination of the branch instructions are all different options at are not "best".  Pick one that suits you best and is easiest to maintain.

Comment: These are all very nice workarounds, but you didn't answer the question what, if anything, is wrong with the simple branch that the OP used.